# HTML, BOOTSTRAP CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap css is not included in IE8 and below version.

i have included bootstrap responsive css in our files. and given the class name 
"row-fluid" for the featured products. 
and for each wrapper image in the featured products i have given class names as
"span3 prod-new featured-list".

See [here](http://demo2.softsolutions4u.com/newts4u/includes/templates/ts4u/css/stylesheet_bootstrap.css)

the styles are included but not added in the Developer tools in IE8..
Hence the images wrapper is shown as block level element in IE8 and below version.
Please check [this](http://demo2.softsolutions4u.com/newts4u/) link,

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is one way to get responsive behaviour with IE7 and IE8. As mentioned above the problem is that these older browsers don't support @media requests.

The solution is to use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) with older IE7 and IE8.

You can do this by downloading respond.js, installing it on your site and placing the following in the head of your page

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
<script src="path-to/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

or you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to test if the visitor's browser supports media queries and if it doesn't load respond.js . Downlod and save respond.js to your site as above, the place the following in the head of your page

```
<script>
Modernizr.load([
{
// test if browser supports medial queries
test : Modernizr.mq('only all'),
// If not, load the respond.js file
nope : 'path-to/respond.js'
}
]);
</script>
```

If you can't get either of the above methods to work for you, you can try using [CSS3-mediaqueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) instead of respond.js. They both work well.

Good luck ... it is an interesting time for web design!

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Bootstrap uses HTML5 and **CSS3** which is sadly but a fact that is not supported in IE8 and lower version. Please check the page in IE9 you wont find this discrepancy. You have to override the existing responsive CSS3 to handle IE8 version. Try using media OR screen width & height and other properties.

Hope this helps you in understand why it does not work in IE8

Comment: Please tell me how to use  "media" OR "screen width & height" and other properties

Comment: The problem is IE8 is never going to support HTML5 and CSS3, you need to tweak your CSS code to have a default behavior for IE8 browser. Media or Screen width & height will work on IE9 and above, specifying @media only screen and (max-width:632px) will ignore IE8 all together and apply it only Android devices which supports HTML5 and CSS3 (again Android devices having Cupcake and below wont have the CSS3 behavior), so cautioning on using the twitter bootstrap framework on the above points